# How to clear all fields in a bit-field struct, except one?

Tags: c

I have this definition:

```
typedef struct {
   int foo :1;
   int bar :1;
   int baz :1;
   ...
} bitfield;
bitfield bf = {0};
```

In my code I want to clear the whole bit field without modifying `bar`.

One solution would be:

```
bool temp = bf.bar;
*(*long)&bf = 0;
bf.bar = temp;
```

Is there a proper way that does not require any temporary boolean?

Comment: Be careful with that clearing, if you have fewer or equal number of bits that fits in an `int`  then on 64-bit machines you could be writing out of bounds if `sizeof(long) == 8` (i.e. if `long` is 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits). You are also breaking the strict aliasing rule with that cast. A better solution would be to use `memset` instead (like `memset(&bf, 0, sizeof bf)`)

Comment: Ehm, Either you want to clear the whole bitfield or you don't! And your code invokes undefined behaviour. A a general advice: don't use bitfield `struct`s. Use masking and shifts directly (they are used behind the scenes anyway).

Comment: `*(*long)&bf = 0;` is a syntax error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C bitfield-`struct`s are not a good use for single bits. Better use an `unsigned int` and shift/masking. This is done in the background anyway. Best use fixed width types, e.g. `uint32_t`, etc..

The code in your example invokes undefined behaviour as I stated in a comment already. You violate the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. Never use it like this.

However, you can use a compound literal:

```
bf = (bitfield){ .bar = bf.bar };
```

to keep `.bar` and set all other fields to `0`.

Note there is another problem with your code: you use `int`. It is implementation-specific if a a bitfield with `int` type is actually signed or unsigned. So each field can either hold `0` and `1` or `0` and `-1` on typical implementations. So you leave this to the implementation. `_Bool` OTOH is always unsigned with the values `0` and `1`. This is the same as logical operators yield.
Better use boolean fields directly:

```
typedef struct {
    bool foo : 1;
    ...
} bitfield;
```

(Mind the the `;`s)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your first argument. I am using bit-fields on an embedded target they greatly improve readability and modularity. I can agree masking and shifting is the most optimized solution for bit manipulation, but it is also prone to errors.

Comment: @nowox: They don't increase modularity actually. And readability is a matter of preference. Use an `enum` to name the bits and use `uint32_t i = `1<<BF_BAR;` e.g to have only one bit set. Using a set of common macros for set/clear/test a bit will make it clear. I don't use bitfield `struct`s **especially on embedded systems. Note that the standard gives almost no guarantee about how bitfield structs are layed out, etc. For me, they are a no-go. And get custom to using fixed width types and be careful using signed integers!

Comment: Beware of bit-fields on some embedded targets, particularly if efficiency is important.  I've come across a few compilers that will encode any access as a sequence of read, shift, AND/OR, write operations, where a single AND/OR is generated when using the `unsigned int` implementation.  This is a particularly important consideration when coding interrupt service routines as the compound statement is non-atomic.

Comment: @MikeofSST: There is no guarantee for any such operations to be atomic anyway. If you rely on a particular implementation generating atomic code, your code is broken already. OTOH, if your implementation supports them, you can make the `struct` atomic. Anyway, this is not about atomicity and that leads way too far. (And a rubbish compiler will generate rubbish code in other places, too. Thats the reason we profile critical code one way or the other)

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I agree.  I made the mistake of expecting the compiler to generate atomic code for a bit-field (my target having `BSET` and `BCLR` instructions) that was used to indicate state information to an ISR.  Debugging the result was my punishment for doing so!  Regrettably, we're often stuck with no option but less-than-perfect compilers.  The plus side, for me at least, is that they do encourage writing more robust code.  :-)

Comment: @MikeofSST: Even the presence of such instructions does not guarantee the compiler uses them **under all circumstances**. A typical scenario is to cache the values in a register for a portion of the code for instance. While this is not possible for `volatile`, there are other problems with them. (Note that I already strongly discourage from using such `structs`, even more in critical code.

Comment: @M.M: Thanks, edited. It actually makes it even worse to use `int` for single bits.

Comment: You could also use `unsigned int foo :1;`, which has the (perhaps small) advantage of being portable to pre-C99 implementations, and the (perhaps greater) advantages of extending to wider bit fields.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sure, `bool` is useless for more than 1 bit wide fields. But as much as I understand, OP wants to use single bits. Unsing `bool` thus is the natural choice. Another advantage is that is might generate leaner code on 8-bit CPUs than `int` etc. Personally, I don't use bitfield `struct`s normally. Most times they are not worth the trouble they introduce. Call me "control freak", but it is surprising what some compilers generate for a bitfield-struct implementation compared to shift/masking:-)